# Why we can't tag users while asking the questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

- Some of users can just answer the problem what you'll be facing recently, so tagging them will be a lot more useful.
- Tagging will give a quicker response, for valid questions.
- If the tagged user don't like the question or something like the question is not relevant for them, then they can remove their tag which will end the pain of notification only in one click.
- If tagged user answered the question then not only we'll have quick solution, but there will be lesser unanswered questions. As here everyone knows that we are having vote up and down for questions but still most of the questions are unanswered not for days but for months or perhaps even a year.

Consider the scenario if you wanna have an urgent help and you don't have the privilege to set so called Bounties, so that users will be attracted towards your question. In that situation tags will be very helpful not only for new users but also for the existing ones.

Comment: Users don't want to be tagged in questions.

Comment: So there can be a functionality so that user can untag them and perhaps if you don't like the user you can also block the user.No offense I am just giving suggestion but try to think again @Flexo  by considering the facts I wrote above.

Comment: The fact is that if you make it easy to harass experts you will drive them away and experts are the lifeblood of this site.

Comment: Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41474/request-a-specific-expert-on-a-subject-to-answer-your-question and related questions are relevant.

Comment: I Agree that there are consequences and harassment is one of them too. Your point is valid  @Flexo.

Comment: Also, Think of Jon Skeet in this scenario

Comment: God that would be annoying.

Comment: @Rahul  Jon Skeet?

Comment: @ashishraaj He is LEGEND http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet

Comment: What in Cthulhu's thunderpants gave you the idea that this would be a good idea??

Comment: +1 to this question though it has so many downvotes. It gave me a new perspective.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 1. *Some of users can just answer the problem what you'll be facing recently, so tagging them will be a lot more useful.*

What if simply they're not active at that time?

> 2. *Tagging will give a quicker response, for valid questions.*

Are you trying to say that the current response speed (in average) is not good enough? I beg to differ, seriously.

> 3. *If the tagged user don't like the question or something like the question is not relevant for them, then they can remove their tag which will end the pain of notification only in one click.*

Why bother? If anyone's interested, lot of available filtering options are there.

> 4. *If tagged user answered the question then not only we'll have quick solution, but there will be lesser unanswered questions. As here everyone knows that we are having vote up and down for questions but still most of the questions are unanswered not for days but for months or perhaps even a year.*

Really? Can you show some stats backing up *"most of the questions are unanswered not for days but for months or perhaps even a year."*? I have some stats [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) which says otherwise.

So, TL;DR , it is good (IMHO, best) as it is currently. You always have an option to chat with the available users to request clarifications.

<sup>P.S - Above are my personal opinion. YMMV.</sup>

Comment: I love how you answer without even touching the "OMG THINK OF HOW CERTAIN USERS WILL GET SPAMMED" issue :P. It gives another slew of arguments to stop this feature :D.