# Tag of people with significant reputation along with topic tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Active user (I am calling it **X**) who spend significant time to the questions of a tag (eg Java, MongoDB) know about to the other user (calling it **Y**) who answers many questions.

Sometimes X needs to ask a question & he knows Y is the best person to answer his question. But he can't tag Y in the comment (*until Y has commented or answered*). For this case, **there should be a tag for that person** & while putting tags for questions, X can add tag `Y` so that Y can see his question.

We can put a limit for such kind of eligibility from Y side. Y must have a significant reputation (say 2000 reputation under that tag) and to avoid so many questions & amateur questions, X should also have some eligibility to add `Y` tag (say 500 reputation under that tag).

Wouldn't it be a cool feature?

**Note: It's upto Y if he wants his tag or not.**

**Edit:** My question is similar to [Why we can't tag users while asking the questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290399/why-we-cant-tag-users-while-asking-the-questions)
 But I am putting in a different way.

Say we have a tag `abc`.

- Total users = 10000 (I think this is good figure for a tag with more than average popularity)
- **Y-like** people: 100 (Top 1% or with significant reputation)
- Interested in having their name tag: 25 (say 25%)
- **X-like** people: 1000 (Top 10% or with significant reputation)

These 25 **Y-like** people want to answer questions & these 1000 **X-like** people will not ask amateur questions or spam Y with lots of questions.

What's the flow in this suggestion?

Comment: If *user Y* spends a **significant** amount of time in *tag-whatever* what makes you think they won't see the question at hand? I could see this quickly getting out of hand.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ maybe partying or going to holidays.

Comment: Exactly my point with the *getting out of hand quickly*. If I was away on holiday I wouldn't want people bugging me.  That's just my opinion though..

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ so that you can check the questions (on which people want your opinion) later (_after coming back_)

Comment: I think you're missing the point though, everything we do here is **optional**, we aren't obligated to do anything, not voting, flagging, answering questions.. any of it.. and giving users the ability to tag other members requesting their help just doesn't seem like it really fits within that sort of model.. Also, users that don't mind being contacted directly usually have some sort of contact information available in their profile.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ This tag will make it easy rather than mailing on personal Id or something like this. Don't you think so?

Comment: Contributing answers to SO is a *voluntary* activity.  Just like you, SO subject experts choose how to spend their free time.  If it is spent on writing SO answers then everybody is ahead, if it is spent playing with the kids then the kids are ahead.  Demanding that they spend their free time on specific questions is drastically unreasonable.  And not just to the kids.  They already spend a significant part of the day involuntarily solving problems.  It is called "job", everybody expects to get paid for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

This idea would *simply* not work!

Why?

1. People who have questions will tag / target some *high-rep-people* **always** - Jon Skeet, Hans Passant, Marko Toplonik, Avinash Raj etc. This will **most probably** irritate them.
2. This goes against the basic ideology of SO - **don't look at who answered, look at the quality of the answer**. A user with 1 rep can give an answer that is 1000 times better than a user with 10000 rep.
3. OPs will spend more time doing research on the people they have to tag in a post instead of doing research on their question itself.

Comment: 1.  high-rep-people who don't want to irritate don't opt for tag  2. It's not about quality -  These people know the topic very well So, good candidate to answer that question.  3/ OP is also a experienced user (not easy to be in 10%, is it?), he knows people I guess.

Comment: There are thousands of people with 1000+ rep. Ask a good question twice and you might end up with that rep.  There will always be people on SO who can answer your question. I see no good reason for tagging people *personally* . I am not saying that your idea is bad, I am saying that it won't work on SO. Everybody would want Jon Skeet to answer their questions :P

Comment: don't go for 1000+ go for the top 1% or whatever. Maybe Jon Skeet don't opt for his tag..:P

Comment: @dev - Then this feature will not be applicable to the *other* 99 %. Also, if you are among SO's top 1% (overall), then you should probably be really smart :P

Comment: Exactly that's my point this is feature for smart people...:P

Comment: smart people do have questions. Don't they?

Comment: @dev - They do. Yes

Comment: say X is in top 100 users in Java (assuming X am smart & generally answers questions..:P ). Is it bad if he asks the question from Jon Skeet (_Assuming Jon Skeet opt for the tag means he wants to have such questions_)?

Comment: @dev - Probably not.. But I think this will probably be rejected as its not directed at the masses :P

Comment: Why should high-rep users asking questions be treated any differently than anyone else?

Comment: What's bad in providing this features to the top users (_who put more efforts on SO_)?

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ - Thats what I am saying. They should not be treated in a different way

Comment: @dev - That is not how SO works. :)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ like the same say people with some reputation can answer, some more then downvote.. some more something else. like this.

Comment: _"2. It's not about quality - These people know the topic very well So, good candidate to answer that question"_ And if you know the topic very well, you are likely to provide a quality answer, again making it about the quality and not about who provided the quality.